# My FlinkKafkaProducer011 needs fewer arguments than is supposed to

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I’m having difficulties with FlinkKafkaConnector.

Although I have imported the `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer011`, I got the following error.

```
Too many arguments for constructor FlinkKafkaProducer011
```

According to [this site](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaProducer011.html), the arguments are correct. However, my IntelliJ shows this definition.

```
public FlinkKafkaProducer011() {
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image: The error I got]

**UPDATE**

Here is the IDE definition.

```
public class FlinkKafkaProducer011 {
    public FlinkKafkaProducer011() {
    }

    public static class NextTransactionalIdHint extends org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.NextTransactionalIdHint {
        public NextTransactionalIdHint() {
        }
    }

    public static class TransactionStateSerializer {
        public TransactionStateSerializer() {
        }

        public static final class TransactionStateSerializerSnapshot extends SimpleTypeSerializerSnapshot<KafkaTransactionState> {
            public TransactionStateSerializerSnapshot() {
                super(org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.TransactionStateSerializer::new);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ContextStateSerializer {
        public ContextStateSerializer() {
        }

        public static final class ContextStateSerializerSnapshot extends SimpleTypeSerializerSnapshot<KafkaTransactionContext> {
            public ContextStateSerializerSnapshot() {
                super(org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.ContextStateSerializer::new);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class NextTransactionalIdHintSerializer {
        public NextTransactionalIdHintSerializer() {
        }

        public static final class NextTransactionalIdHintSerializerSnapshot extends SimpleTypeSerializerSnapshot<org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.NextTransactionalIdHint> {
            public NextTransactionalIdHintSerializerSnapshot() {
                super(org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer.NextTransactionalIdHintSerializer::new);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please specify what `flink-connector-kafka` version you use ?

From what I can see, the `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer011` you have used is just a compatibility class from `flink-connector-kafka_2.11` jar and the right producer to use is   `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer`.

As far as I understand, the javadoc https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaProducer011.html is relevant for `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer011` producer from `flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11` artifact.

So, I would suggest to either switch to `org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer` or change dependency to `flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11` jar.

Comment: Thank you for you reply!
I have changed to use `flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11` and (Flink version is 1.9.3) but somehow unable to use the method.
As I said I do not want to use the deprecated method.

Comment: Ah, I found that I can build this file but IntelliJ still shows a different method...

Comment: @DIOHABARA, have you re-imported changes(dependencies) in IntelliJ ? `flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11` has the `FlinkKafkaProducer011` with the required constructor:

```java
 public FlinkKafkaProducer011(String brokerList, String topicId, SerializationSchema<IN> serializationSchema) {
  this(
   topicId,
   new KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper<>(serializationSchema),
   getPropertiesFromBrokerList(brokerList),
   Optional.of(new FlinkFixedPartitioner<IN>()));
 }
```

Comment: Thanks!
I succeeded!